# Ruby on Rails: Failing to convert value in hash to float

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, floating-point

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here.

I have the following hash placed in variable "simple_lable". Calling inspect on it works fine, but I cannot seem to access any of the numerical values. .to_i comes out as 0, .to_f comes out as 0.0 and to_s comes out blank

```
puts "**************************"
puts simple_label.inspect
puts simple_label["margin_top"].to_f
puts simple_label["margin_bottom"].to_f
puts simple_label["margin_right"].to_f
puts simple_label["margin_left"].to_f
puts simple_label["paper_size"]
puts "**************************"
```

results in

```
**************************
{"paper_size"=>"LETTER", "top_margin"=>36, "bottom_margin"=>36, "left_margin"=>15.822, "right_margin"=>15.822, "columns"=>3, "rows"=>10, "column_gutter"=>15, "row_gutter"=>0}
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
LETTER
**************************
```

So the values are there, but I just can't seem to get hold of them correctly.

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your hash keys are incorrect. Your hash has, for example, `top_margin`, as a key, but you are trying to reference a key of `margin_top`. The hash will return `nil` for a non-existent key, and `to_f`, `to_i` are giving zero, and `to_s` giving blank for a `nil` hash value.

Comment: You are so right (slaps hand on forehead!). I guess sometimes it just takes another pair of eyes, thanks very much :)

Comment: @BjornForsberg no problem. I didn't see it at first glance.